# Bison C++ invalid use of unique_ptr

Tags: unique-ptr, bisonc++

I am writing a bison file for parsing.
In a declared grammar rule, I'm trying to create a unique_ptr pointing to a syntax tree node (DeclAST) that contains multiple symbol table entries. However, an error message was encountered:

```
parser.y:73:19: error: invalid use of ‘class std::unique_ptr<DeclAST>’
   73 |$$ = std::make_unique<DeclAST>(syms,2,$3);
```

The code at line 73 of parser.y and the context-sensitive code are as follows:

```
ConstDecl:{declare =1;} CONST Btype COnstDefs{declare=0;} SEMI
{
$$ = std::make_unique<DeclAST>(syms,2,$3); 
...
}
```

I have made it clear that the node type of ConstDecl is DeclAST:

```
%type< unique_ptr<DeclAST> > ConstDecl
%type< int > Btype
```

For Btype, the corresponding code in parser.y is:

```
Btype: ICONST {$$ = INT_TYPE;}
       | FCONST {$$ = FLOAT_TYPE;}
```

Also:

```
#define INT_TYPE 258
#define FLOAT_TYPE 259
#define SIZE 100
```

I checked my definition of DeclAST:

```cpp
class DeclAST
{
   Symtab** names;
   int names_count;
   int data_type;

   public:
      DeclAST(Symtab** s, int nsc, int dty)
        :names(s), names_count(nsc), data_type(dty);
};
```

For Symtab:

```
Symtab** syms = (Symtab**) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(Symtab*));
```

I also included the header file . All things seem correct.
Any detailed help will be appreciated.